# Netty: How can I reuse the same `FullHttpResponse`?

Tags: java, http, netty

In my project I'd like to write the same `FullHttpResponse` to many clients for a performance boost.

Previously I have written the same `ByteBuf` for a custom protocol, and used `retain` to prevent the buf from being released after writing.

Unfortunately with `FullHttpResponse` (`DefaultFullHttpResponse`) my technique doesn't seem to work. The first time I write the response clients receive the response correctly, but the next write doesn't go through.

I did a simple `System.out.println` test to make sure nothing was blocking and that my code was executed entirely, and my test showed that yes, nothing is blocking and the request does seem to go through.

I am using the Netty `4.1.0.Final` release from Maven Central.

---

The pipeline only has an `HttpServerCodec(256, 512, 512, false, 64)` and my `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpRequest>`, which I send the `FullHttpResponse` from.

Here's a simplified version of my inbound handler:

```
class HTTPHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpRequest> {

    private static final FullHttpResponse response =
            new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, 
                                        HttpResponseStatus.OK,
                                        Unpooled.buffer(8).writeLong(0),
                                        false);

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest msg) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(response.retain(), ctx.voidPromise());
    }

}
```

Comment: You could also consider serializing it once (manually running it through the codecs in the pipeline? Or even a fixed String `"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n.."`), then sending that result. Your current approach still has to serialize the response each time (unless there is a cache I'm not aware of).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `response.duplicate().retain()` or if using Netty 4.1.x you can also use `response.retainedDuplicate()`.

This is needed to ensure you get separate reader/writer indices.

Comment: But then, what happens to the duplicated response object? Will it ever be garbage collected, since its reference count might never be zero?

Comment: Once you pass it to ctx.write(...) you transfer ownership and so the pipeline / channel is responsible to release it.